# Add gap in OxyPlot line series

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot in a Xamarin forms application. In a line series there can be missing data and I need to have a gap in the line to indicate the missing data.

Here's an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image: Plot created with flot in javascript. Show "hole" in values]

How can I create a graph that contains a gap like this?

Comment: Make 2 series and represent the empty value on one of them. Or make one serie per gap. Could you show an image of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @Kirenenko, one series for each continues part is an option. I will try this if no other options exists.

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution. By adding a Double.NaN value in the datapont, holes are created.

```
new DataPoint(15, Double.NaN)
```

Comment: This works well. You should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One could also use

```
DataPoint.Undefined
```

For example,

```
 series1.Points.Add(DataPoint.Undefined);
```